# How to use ActionBarPullToRefresh on android

Tags: java, android, twitter, android-actionbar

I want to implement ActionBarBullTorefresh in my android project but it give me errors.
Here are the code.
Please help me.

```
package com.mejorandola.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mejorandola.android.adapter.TweetAdapter;
import com.mejorandola.android.models.Tweet;
import com.mejorandola.android.utils.ConstantsUtils;
import com.mejorandola.android.utils.TwitterUtils;

public class TimelineActivity extends Activity implements OnRefreshListener{
private ListView listView;
private PullToRefreshAttacher pullToRefreshAttacher;

private void updateListView(ArrayList<Tweet> tweets){
    listView.setAdapter(new TweetAdapter(this, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets));
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    new GetTimeLineTask().execute();

    pullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this);
    pullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(listView, this);

}

class GetTimeLineTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ArrayList<Tweet>>{ 
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TimelineActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.label_tweet_search_loader));
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Tweet> doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

        try {
            String timeline = TwitterUtils.getTimelineForSearchTerm(ConstantsUtils.SEARCHTAG);
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(timeline);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("statuses");
            JSONObject tweetJsonObject;

            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                tweetJsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                Tweet tweet = new Tweet();

                tweet.setName(tweetJsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("name"));
                tweet.setScreenName(tweetJsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("screen_name"));
                tweet.setProfileImagrUrl(tweetJsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("profile_image_url"));
                tweet.setText(tweetJsonObject.getString("text"));
                tweet.setCreateAt(tweetJsonObject.getString("created_at"));

                tweets.add(i,tweet);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tweets;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Tweet> tweets) {
        super.onPostExecute(tweets);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if(tweets.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(TimelineActivity.this,getResources().getString(R.string.label_tweets_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            updateListView(tweets);
            Toast.makeText(TimelineActivity.this,getResources().getString(R.string.label_tweets_downloaded), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pullToRefreshAttacher.setRefreshComplete();
        }

    }.execute();

}
}
```

This is the log.

> 07-01 13:16:14.568: D/AndroidRuntime(19799): Shutting down VM
>   07-01 13:16:14.568: W/dalvikvm(19799): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41747ba8)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799): Process: com.mejorandola.android, PID: 19799
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mejorandola.android/com.mejorandola.android.TimelineActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher$EnvironmentDelegate.getContextForInflater(PullToRefreshAttacher.java:811)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher.(PullToRefreshAttacher.java:159)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher.get(PullToRefreshAttacher.java:105)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshAttacher.get(PullToRefreshAttacher.java:90)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at com.mejorandola.android.TimelineActivity.onCreate(TimelineActivity.java:38)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>   07-01 13:16:14.578: E/AndroidRuntime(19799):    ... 11 more

Comment: Why you don't use the PullToRefresh of Android inside support library?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Because i need to use this library for a homework.

Comment: The problem is here TimelineActivity.java:38

Comment: @MarcoAcierno and how do i fix it?

Comment: It's a null pointer. Put a breakpoint and check what is null

Answer (score -1):

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(19799): at com.mejorandola.android.TimelineActivity.onCreate(TimelineActivity.java:38)
En la linea 38 esta la solucion

    pullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this);

por 
    pull_to_refresh_attacher = (this.getAttacher();
    pull_to_refresh_attacher.addRefreshableView(grid, this);
```